# Download ftp file with auth

Tags: python

I am trying to download an ftp file from a server:

```
ftp://i.example.net/upload/file.csv
```

I can do this using `urllib`, without the authentication:

```
urllib.urlretrieve('ftp://server/path/to/file', 'file')
```

How would I do it with the authentication:

```
- Username: 'david'
- Password: 'password'
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5188215/2269620

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize an FTP handler like so:

```
ftp = urllib2.FTPHandler()
```

Then connect with arguments like so:

```
ftp.connect_ftp(username, password, ...)
```

Lastly, open a request under the ftp object:

```
ftp.ftp_open(request_object)
```

Comment: I think the question is about downloading from a ftp server with credentials.